# Can the BackgroundImage have transparent parts on the transparent Form background?

Tags: c#, winforms, background-image, windows-forms-designer

When I load a .png BackgroundImage with 50% opacity on a transparent/invisible Form background, the Form simply shows the Background behind the image again.
So this probably means that I can't use the BackgroundImage itself when I want to see Desktop symbols through it - it has to be displayed in a pictureBox in any case?

Comment: You're looking for something called [Layered Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows), which can be accomplished via P/Invoking various Win32 functions.

Comment: A Form can only have tranparency via TranparencyKey color, which mean only 0 or 100 transparency.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Layered Windows and P/Invoking method was a suitable solution for my project.